# Apply styles with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Given this CSS:

```
#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span {
    display:none;
}
```

How would one apply this and unapply it programatically using jQuery?

That is we'd dynamically set this style to none (hide) and "" (show) using jQuery.

Not sure how you create a jQuery id representing `#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span`

For background on why you'd want to do this, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601476/is-it-possible-to-hide-or-manipulate-the-jqgrid-sort-icons).

Comment: `#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span` is not a jQuery ID. It's a CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span").hide();
$("#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span").show();
```

Should do the trick, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show and hide, you can use those jQuery methods:

```
$('#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span').hide();  //hides all the elements that match the selector
```

This will select all the elements that match the CSS selector provided, and will call [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), setting their `style.display` property to `none`.

Calling  [the `.show()` method](http://api.jquery.com/show/) will of course do the opposite of `.hide()`.

Answer (score 1):

To apply and unapply programmatically, you'd do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4c8Aw/

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="click" />

<div id="gbox_MyGrid">
    <div class="s-ico">
        <span>test</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span {
    display:none;
}​
```

**JS**

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $("#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span").toggle();
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

just change the class on the elements

```
$('#gbox_MyGrid .s-ico span').toggleClass('hiddenClass')
```